# How do I change the color of programmatically UIIMage Array Animation?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimageview

I am currently making a Swift application with multiple UIImage elements. I am at the point where I need to add animations into my game. In order to reduce the projects fie size I have made a single shatter animation for every colored glass object. I have successfully changed the Images tint color for the first image in the animation but not the proceeding images. What is the best way to achieve this with the following code?

```
shatterImages = createImagesArray(total: 26, imagePrefix: "Shatter")

func createImagesArray(total: Int, imagePrefix: String) -> [UIImage] {
    var imageArray: [UIImage] = []

    for imageCount in 1..<total {
        let imageName = "\(imagePrefix)-\(imageCount).png"
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)!

        imageArray.append(image)

    }
    return imageArray
}

func animate(imageView: UIImageView, images: [UIImage]) {
    let templateImage = imageView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    imageView.image = templateImage
    imageView.tintColor = UIColor.blue
    imageView.animationImages = images
    imageView.animationDuration = 0.7
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
    imageView.startAnimating()
}

 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                if self.game.correctValue == self.game.rightDiamondValue {
                    self.animate(imageView: self.rightGlass, images: self.shatterImages)
                        self.updateLabel()
                    } else {
                        self.gameOver()
                    }
            }
```

Comment: I don't know if what you are doing is a very good thing because you actually have 26 images which will be load in ram just for one animation... so if you have a lot of animations happening at the same time your app will take all of the ram. You should take a look at SpriteKit animations (sks files), it may correspond to you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UIImage animationImages tint color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27148994/uiimage-animationimages-tint-color)

Comment: @Titouan I am more experienced with spritekit and I would prefer to use it for what I'm doing. But because i'm practicing using UIKit I want to make the animation with the code I have, if possible. If not then I will cop out and redesign the scene with spritekit. but thanks!

Comment: @koen Thanks very much, It worked like a charm!